# Memory usage rapidly increasing using sockets and sending frames in string

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My web application is increasing the memory usage while it is sending frames. I am trying to discover how to fix this. My real problem is to do a video streaming from a Desktop application (coded in C#/Unity3D) to a javascript web page. It works perfectly, except that I have a memory problem in my web browser (chrome). My memory is not freeing and it increase rapidly.

I have coded a experimental code to discover why my memory is not being freed.

I am sending a frame many times per seconds from a node.js server socket to a web client. 
The code of the server is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
 const FRAME = "{\"Data\":\"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\",\"Type\":4}"
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8086");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


http.listen(8877, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8877');

});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: http,
    path: "/images",
    port: 8877,
    autoAcceptConnections: true
});


wsServer.on('connect', function (con)
{   function myFunc () {
        con.sendUTF(FRAME);
        setTimeout(myFunc, 1000/200, 'funky');
    }

    myFunc();
    console.log("connect");

});
```

The client side code is the following:

```html
 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
test
<script>
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8877/images";
websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };

function onMessage(message)
{
  var mes = JSON.parse(message.data); 
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I free the memory? Or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And how exactly do you determine that "your memory is not freeing"?  Do you realize that you're sending a message every 2ms (which translates to 500 messages per second)?  What is the CPU load on both client and server?

Comment: I have edited my post removing socket.io dependencies and using standard websocket. I determine that my memory is not being freed because Task Manager shows that chrome use more and more memory. I send 500 msg per seconds just for rush the testing, if I decrease it to 30 fps the problem is similar but it takes more in increase the memory. How can I measure the CPU load on both? with task Manager?

Comment: Task Manager is a very coarse memory usage indicator.  It only indicates overall process memory.  It does not tell you whether the issue is a garbage collection issue or not.  I'd suggest using heap snapshots to figure out if the actual memory in use by the JS interpreter is going up or not.  I comments about a message every 2ms and asked about CPU usage because if you are keeping the ndoejs processor fully loaded, then it may not have time for proper garbage collection.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help